# Training MSE and irreducible error

Tags: machine-learning

I am currently re-reading the famous book "An Introduction to Statistical Learning".
In chapter 2.2.1, it is written that the irreducible error, $Var(\epsilon)$, "*corresponds to the lowest achievable test MSE among all possible methods*".

I have a sense of why the *training MSE* is not subject to this lower bound, but how can we explain it **mathematically**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sufficiently many parameters, we can overfit to the point where the model memorizes the data.  It is straightforward to see why the training MSE is not subject to this lower bound if we study linear regression.

In linear regression, we want to solve

$$ \underset{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^p}{\mbox{argmin}} \lVert y - X\beta \rVert ^2_2 $$

If $X$ square and full rank, then $ \hat{\beta} = X^{-1}y$.  The training error is hence 0.

Comment: Does it mean that, for the training error, the model variance and the residual variance... sort of... cancel each other? (I know that sounds weird since these are two positive quantites).

Comment: No.  The model variance is very high since you would be overfitting, and the residual variance is estimated to be 0 but in reality is probably a positive number.  It would just appear that there is no residual variance because you've completely overfit the data.